# .htaccess rewriterule URL masking to access files one level above public_html

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

In my filesystem  (php site) I have a series of images in this format:

```
example.com/public_html/profile_image/0/1/564.jpg
```

I would like to store those images in a format like:

```
example.com/profile_image/0/1/564.jpg
```

and then have `.htaccess` silently redirect requests (URL masking) from the former URL `example.com/profile_image/0/1/564.jpg` to the latter filesystem path.

This is basically to have images stored one level above `/public_html` but publicly access them as if they were inside public_html.

Is this possible with a `RewriteRule`?

Comment: `/public_html` shouldn't be in the visible URL-path to begin with - this looks like a misconfiguration in the vHost `DocumentRoot`? "images stored one level above /public_html" - the way you described the location of the images, they would seem to be stored _below_ `/public_html`. "but publicly access them as if they were inside public_html" - but they are inside public_html?

Comment: Sorry, I realized my question was a bit misleading: the filesystem path where I have the images is indeed one level above public_html, images are stored in /home/example.com/profile_image/0/1/564.jpg , while my public document root is /home/example.com/public_html. So I would like to access for example the URL example.com/image/0/1/564.jpg and have apache serve it transparently from /home/example.com/profile_image/0/1/564.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I would like to store those images in a format like:
>
> ```
> example.com/profile_image/0/1/564.jpg
> ```

From your description, you are "storing" the image at `/public_html/profile_image/0/1/564.jpg` and this does not change, but you want to internally rewrite the request from `/profile_image/0/1/564.jpg` (the visible URL-path) to `/public_html/profile_image/0/1/564.jpg`, the underlying filesystem path.

To do this in your root `.htaccess` file you would need to do it like this using mod_rewrite:

```
RewriteEngine On

# Rewrite images from "/profile_image/..." to "public_html/profile_image/..."
RewriteRule ^profile_image/.+\.jpg$ public_html/$0 [L]
```

The `$0` backreference contains the URL-path that is matched by the `RewriteRule` *pattern* (first argument).

---

> In my filesystem (php site) I have a series of images in this format:
>
> ```
> example.com/public_html/profile_image/0/1/564.jpg
> ```

Although (as mentioned in comments), the `/public_html` shouldn't appear in the public HTML space to begin with. This looks like a server misconfiguration, as the `DocumentRoot` would generally point to the `/public_html` directory. But, this presumably doesn't affect only images, does it?